# Won't renew ethernet connection after rebooting modem

Tags: ethernet, internet

I have my Pi directly connected to my modem via ethernet. However the modem craps out every now and then, requiring a hard reboot with the power cable.

But the Pi doesn't renew its connection like my PC does. How can I make it so that the Pi reconnects properly? Right now I have to reboot the Pi from SSH, which is a pain.

Comment: The RPi is not capable of connecting directly to a modem. Do you mean your router?

Comment: It's connected to my cable modem directly. Works fine. Weird? My cable modem has 4 ethernet inputs, so I guess it is a router in some capacity.

Comment: Is this a modem/router combination?

Comment: How do you connect via `ssh` if the ethernet link is down?

Comment: I think what you're both getting at is correct. It is a modem/router combo.

Comment: So, to clarify, your RPi never loses connection to the network, it's the internet that is the problem? As @goldilocks pointed out, if you're able to SSH into the RPi, you have a connection to at least the network.